What residential appliance has a NEMA 5-20 plug?
I see 120V 20A receptacles (5-20R) sold in stores.  Lots of them.  They are not specialty items. And I see them on the walls of houses.  But I have never seen an appliance with a 5-20 plug.  Perhaps they exist in specialized industrial applications ... I don't care about that.  For example I think the janitor's floor polishing machine in my high school used one.  "But that's not important right now".
Residential ... why are these things sold, and why so much?   What device exists that uses one?

Just a thought - perhaps they are sold so often not because someone needs to use a 20A device, but because everyone likes "more" better than "less" so 20A is "better" than 15A

Workshops usually have at least a few of them, not to mention 240V for welding.

Unfortunately, most appliance designers stick to things that will plug into a 5-15R so people won't buy an appliance (which would point out on the box that it needs a 5-20R with pictures, even) and complain that they can't plug it in, even where that appliance would markedly benefit from extra power and would be expected to be located in a place with code-required access to 20A circuits. So it's a reasonable question. +1 Mostly 20A circuits get more 15A things plugged into them before tripping.

I used to help design commercial equipment, and there was a device we were manufacturing that was on the borderline of requiring 5-20P.  There was much debate about whether to pare down the load to get it safely within 5-15P, or risk producing a device requiring 5-20, even for a commercial application.

@KenCarlson and?????? Did you ever decide to go with 5-20 for anything?  But again, for commercial it's less interesting.  The question isn't "does any application exist for these", it is "why are people installing them so much in their homes?"

FWIW I think @izzy is probably right but I hate to be so cynical, I'm waiting for a better answer.  From a product management perspective, if you are selling millions of units, you can afford to put some on the market that cost 5% more to make and sell for 50% or 100% more, and people buy them because it's an extra $2 and it's "better".   You know ... "just in case".

I've almost never seen 5-20 outlets in houses. They are common in commercial though I have always wondered why.

@jay613 The electrical system wasn't my job, so I don't recall what the typical resolution was.  I made the comment to emphasize that device manufacturers can be reluctant to produce equipment requiring 5-20 even for commercial applications.  Implying that consumer device manufacturers would be really reluctant to do so.

I can find 2200W commercial toasters, which I suppose a family with a great deal of toast demand and no budget constraints might buy. Can't even find a toaster oven or microwave oven without it going to 240V at that wattage, though.

@Ecnerwal nice find.  I don't think that's the reason but at least it's something. But here's a new rabbit hole: commercial toasters 1800W with 5-15 plug.  Presumably certain loopholes allow this in a commercial setting.

A toaster or a hair dryer is not a continuous load. A resistance space heater or resistance water heater is a continuous. All 4 use the same heating elements. The difference is that a toaster has a low duty cycle - even in a diner probably 50% at most, and a hair dryer even less. A space heater or water heater can easily run at 100% duty cycle for hours at a time, which means continuous load and 80% derate so max. 1500W.

Same toaster available either way was what I found. Commercial is designed for commercial use; usually built better, more power may or may not apply. The higer wattage with the 5-20P was slightly less expensive.

Ah right.  Duty cycle.  The commercial toasters using 15A on a15A plug are popup not conveyer.  Interesting.

I've seen some beefy PCs that have a 5-20 plug (like some of HP's Z-series workstations). If you're an engineer doing heavy-duty CAD work from home then you might need one.  It's a pretty niche use case, though.

OK we so far have a toaster, a sauna, an old window A/C and a workstation.  Not bad.

Is the T-shaped 5-20R receptacle as safe?  It looks like it would be easier to get a foreign object in (ahh, doesn't matter because that's the neutral leg).  Also the spring contacts can't grab in the middle of the blades of a 15A plug.

Fancier espresso machines. They often can be converted between 15 and 20 A modes.

@BenVoigt The foreign object issue is now taken care of by tamper-resistant receptacles. In ye olden times (and still today for houses with older receptacles) with gadgets like these from Safety 1st via Amazon which will fit fine in a 5-20 and cover the entire receptacle.

@bta It's very hard to find consumer UPSes with decent battery life without buying systems with unnecessarily high power ratings. As a result, a UPS for a high-end desktop computer station that has even ten minutes of backup time will likely have a 20A plug on it.

TL;DR Very Few, because it is a Catch-22
There are currently a number of required 120V 20A circuits in a home:

Bathroom
Kitchen (at least 2)
Laundry Room

Unlike most other circuit sizes, a 20A circuit can have both 15A (5-15) and 20A (5-20) receptacles. The only limitation is that if there is a single receptacle then it must be a 20A (5-20) receptacle.
So the question really becomes: Should I install 5-15 or 5-20 on these circuits? And the answer varies depending on the particular application:

Commercial - 5-20 makes sense so you can plug in the occasional floor polishing machine or big server UPS or whatever
Residential, particularly mass-market builder - 5-15 makes sense so you can use the same 5-15 bottom-of-the-line duplex receptacles everywhere: Required 20A circuits, general-purpose 15A circuits (which will be 15A because that means cheaper 14 AWG wire), etc. Even if 5-15 and 5-20 receptacles cost exactly the same, it is cheaper to only stock one item (or 3 really - standard, GFCI, weather-resistant for outdoors) instead of two (or 6).
Residential - workshop or other locations that may need 20A someday - 5-20
Residential - higher-quality builder - 5-20 on 20A circuits, 5-15 on 15A circuits so that you can always make use of the maximum power available

As far as appliances with 5-20 plugs, they are relatively unusual for residential applications. It is a bit of a Catch-22:

If you are a manufacturer of an appliance, you want to stick with 15A (12A continuous) and a 5-15 plug so that your appliance can be used in any house in the US/Canada, even if it is 100 years old and never had major electrical upgrades.
If you are a typical builder or electrician, you stick with 5-15 for residential installation except when requested (e.g., workshop) because "nobody ever needs it".

The end result is:

Due to inertia (the installed based of 15A circuits and of 15A receptacles on 20A circuits), with the exception of specialty items, nobody makes mass market consumer-grade 120V appliances that require more than a 15A circuit.

Grounding is not exactly the same issue, but while most houses have at least some grounded receptacles, there are plenty of devices still designed to not require a ground because that means you can plug in the appliance anywhere, including an older house that still has plenty of ungrounded receptacles.

Informative and well written as always but respectfully, I think evades the core question with "someday" and "so that you can always" in the most relevant sections.

Not answering the question asked. Like, at all. Changing the question via "so the question really becomes" really just means not answering the question asked, so posing your own which is not, in fact, "what the question becomes" because that wasn't the question.

A well-known discount store carries infrared saunas.  IIRC, it uses the 5-20P.
IIRC, we had a window-mount air conditioner that needed 120V 20A and had a 5-20P.
Probably there are some smaller hot tubs.
To generalize:  appliances that are power-hungry, but not too much for 120V, and sufficiently expensive or desirable that installing a dedicated 120V 20A circuit will be acceptable to the homeowner.

I remember seeing large window A/C units with those plugs. They were likely needed when most homes had 15amp ungrounded receptacles. This assured the units weren't plugged in anything other than the dedicated outlet. This does not explain why they are so common today.

Often (not always) the large window ACs were the 6-20P for 240V at 20A, which looks like a 5-20P seen in a mirror.

5-20 outlets don't have to be dedicated.  5-15 outlets can be dedicated.  Putting a 5-20 plug on a 1440W A/C as a way of forcing customers to install dedicated outlets would be a very unlikely, and probably suicidal, business decision.   I'm with Ecnerwal, I think you are remembering 240V units.  Those are common.
